# Creating a datatable form an array for Google Chart

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I need to create a data table to pass a google chart starting from an array: I retrieve data, as example temperature, from OpenWeather API in PHP and I convert the temperature array into a javascript array. From this array I build the data table with this code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var temp=new Array();
    <?php
    for($i=0;$i<count($temperatura);$i++){?>
    temp[<?php echo $i; ?>]="<?php echo "$temperatura[$i]"; ?>";
    <?php 
    }?>

      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

      function drawChart() {

         var data2 = new Array();

         data2[0] = [ 'Data', 'Temp.' ];
         for (i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                data2[i + 1] = [ '10/04/2017', 'temp[i]' ];  
         }


        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data2, false);
        document.write(data); //this cause the message [object Object]

        var options = {
        chart: {
          title: 'Box Office Earnings in First Two Weeks of Opening',
          subtitle: 'in millions of dollars (USD)'
        },
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        axes: {
          x: {
            0: {side: 'top'}
          }
        }
      };

      var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

      chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
       }    
  }
  </script>

  <div id="chart_div"></div>
```

In the browser I see the message [object Object] and I don't understand what is wrong. Can help me?
I read some similar questions but they don't solve my problem.

Comment: it seems the data table has rows: 35..but when I try to print the graph the datatable is null and the graph is empty. How can I print the data table?

Comment: Positioning the document.write suggested after the for cicle the result is:  [["Data","Temperatura"],[["2017-04-30 15:00:00","17.51"]],[["2017-04-30 18:00:00","15.34"]],[["2017-04-30 21:00:00","12.55"]],.othe values...,[["2017-05-04 21:00:00","13.3"]]]

Comment: Using document.write(JSON.stringify(data)); after var data=.... the result is "{\"cols\":[{\"label\":\"Data\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"label\":\"Temperatura\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"rows\":[{\"c\":[{\"v\":\"2017-04-30 15:00:00\"},{\"v\":\"17.51\"}]}, ....hoping this can helpful to solve my problem.